# Why can I only fire this function once?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
const sliderTextChange = document.getElementsByClassName('slider') // text change

const changeSliderText = change => {
  const sliderLeft = document.getElementsByClassName('switch-left')
  const sliderRight = document.getElementsByClassName('switch-right')

  for (let i = 0; i < change.length; i++) {
    change[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      sliderRight[i].style.display = 'flex';
      sliderLeft[i].style.display = 'none';
    });
  }
}

changeSliderText(sliderTextChange);
```

This is one of the many sliders on the website:

```
<div class="flex-column">
  <h3>Text Colour</h3>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-back"></div>
    <div class="slider-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <h3 class="switch-left">White</h3>
  <h3 class="switch-right">Black</h3>
</div>
```

This function is quite a lot like many other functions in my code but they're only firing once. AKA I fire the event listener and but then I can't fire it again.

What's the issue here?

Comment: Which function are you talking about? The click handler or the outer function that sets up the handlers? And how do you know that it's only firing once?

Comment: Is this code inside an event handler?

Comment: `const sliderLeft = document.getElementsByClassName('switch-left')`  You do know this is going select ALL Dom nodes with class `switch-left`?  And as such every DOM element with class `slider` is going to do the same code?

Comment: I'm talking about changeSliderText(). This code is inside a function called displayFunction() which is one of many functions intended to rewrite code in a div when called. Basically when I click on `slider` the event fires once but not again.

Comment: yes @Keith. I have multiple sliders. I'll put the HTML in the question.

Comment: Yes, the problem is if your always selecting the same `switch-left` for every slider, then it won't have any effect.  Your selector for `switch-left` & `switch-right` need to be specific to the selected slider.  Looking at your HTML you should be able to get from `change[i].parentElement.querySelector(".switch-left")`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to simplify your code and keep the `scope` to be modular and reusable view.

```js
function bindEvent() {
 const sliderList = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
 [...sliderList].forEach((slider) => slider.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const left = slider.parentElement.querySelector('.switch-left');
    const right = slider.parentElement.querySelector('.switch-right');
    const leftDisplay = left.style.display || 'flex';
    const rightDisplay = right.style.display || 'none';
    left.style.display = rightDisplay;
    right.style.display = leftDisplay;
 }, false));
}

window.onload = bindEvent;
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="slider"> - SLIDER 1 - </button>
  <div class="switch-left">L</div><div class="switch-right">R</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="slider"> - SLIDER 2 - </button>
  <div class="switch-left">L</div><div class="switch-right">R</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="slider"> - SLIDER 3 - </button>
  <div class="switch-left">L</div><div class="switch-right">R</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="slider"> - SLIDER 4 - </button>
  <div class="switch-left">L</div><div class="switch-right">R</div>
</div>
```

Parameters you have chosen for your function are not really intuitive and make your example more complex.

We use `querySelector`, it's nicer to read but if you prefer speed, just go for `getElementsByClassName`, it also works on any DOM element.